# applescript resize pictures on user input

Tags: image, resize, applescript

I am trying to achieve some automation in my current workflow. I'd like to drop images to my applescript application, then have it autoresize to the size as set by the user.
I prompt the user a dialog, where one can enter the pixelsize for width, then have the script do the donkey work.

For some reason it is not running properly, and for  the life of my i can't figure out why. 
Any and all help is very much appreciated!

Here's the script:

```
display dialog "What is the desired size?" default answer "64"
set my_answer to text returned of result

on open some_items
    repeat with this_item in some_items
        try
            rescale_and_save(this_item)
        end try
    end repeat
end open


to rescale_and_save(this_item)



    tell application "Image Events"
        launch
        set the target_width to my_answer
        -- open the image file
        set this_image to open this_item

        set typ to this_image's file type

        copy dimensions of this_image to {current_width, current_height}
        if current_width is greater than current_height then
            scale this_image to size target_width
        else
            -- figure out new height
            -- y2 = (y1 * x2) / x1
            set the new_height to (current_height * target_width) / current_width
            scale this_image to size new_height
        end if

        tell application "Finder" to set new_item to ¬
            (container of this_item as string) & "scaled." & (name of this_item)
        save this_image in new_item as typ

    end tell
end rescale_and_save
```

Comment: what do you mean by "it's not running properly" what is it NOT doing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote this script a while ago. It will re-sample an image so its largest dimension is the input value.

```
on open of myFiles
    set my_answer to text returned of (display dialog "What is the desired size?" default answer "64")

    repeat with aFile in myFiles
        set filePath to aFile's POSIX path
        set bPath to (do shell script "dirname " & quoted form of filePath)

        tell application "System Events" to set {fileName, fileExt} to {name, name extension} of aFile
        set baseName to text 1 thru ((get offset of "." & fileExt in fileName) - 1) of fileName

        do shell script "sips " & quoted form of aFile's POSIX path & " -Z " & my_answer & " --out " & quoted form of (bPath & "/" & baseName & "-" & my_answer & "." & fileExt as text)

    end repeat
end open
```